# setup and deployment by reading bios of user system

Tags: visual-studio, setup-project

am using c# vs-2005

am trying to setup & deployment of project and did it very simple by adding assembly and prerequesite of the project on setup properties.

but i want to deploy it by professionally like to first read bios of user system and detect the HDD serial. after detaction of HDD Serial i want to generate my own key to allow user to do the setup.

Narration :- " I want to run my application on specific HDD. For new HDD user Shoul Contect Me"

suggest me proper way or any proper coding will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do that in your installer? Such a mechanism in an MSI could be circumvented very easily.

Comment: if any other way than please suggest. thx

Comment: You don't want your software shared/copied? Not sure id this is the best solution. Can't you use online activation or something?

Comment: ur right sir,

i want my project personilize and wants to distribute at licence basis. and for that the user bios reading is important for me. As per ur suggestion why don't i go to online? it's true but not now, i will put my application at online later. but now what to do? Any suggestion than please. It will appreciated. thx

Answer (score 1):

There are an number of software licensing/activation systems available, we use [Nalpeiron](http://www.nalpeiron.com/) and have come across so many issues with various system configurations, that I wouldn't dream of trying to develop something like this yourself.

Primarily we use it for online activation, but you can do USB key dongle, phone, email, etc. depending on your exact requirements.

Comment: thx sir for ur feedback, but sir is it possible or not to read bios system specifically HDD in c# if yes then guid me.

Comment: Sorry, I don't program in .NET